# How to tie one variable to another

Tags: c#

I have this bit of code:

```
Brick brick1= new Brick(parent.X - 1,parent.Y);
```

X & Y are integers,

Basiclly what i want to do is: when the x of the parent brick changes, the x of brick1 changes,where it dosnt matter the value of `parent.X`, `brick1.X` will always be equal to `parent.X - 1`

Is there an way of accomplishing this?

Comment: How would pointers help?  In C# classes are reference types which act much like pointers.

Comment: What you need is a reference to the other brick and a getter that calculates `X` on the fly.

Comment: You'd need to make the Brick class aware of its parent, add a field of the parent type.  And change the constructor so you can use new Brick(parent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `Brick` is not a struct you could do this.  You could also do this through inheritance with a ChildBrick class but unless you need the added complication, at least in my mind, it is simpler to just allow `Brick` to have a parent that is a `Brick` and add a constructor for the parent.  Then if you retrieve a value and it needs to be computed from the parent you just check for whether you have a parent and calculate accordingly.

```
class Brick
{
    private Brick _parent;
    private int _x;
    private int _y;

    Brick(Brick parent) {_parent = parent);}
    Brick(int x, int y)
    {
        _x = x;
        _y=y;
    }

    public int X
    {
        get
        {
            if (_parent != null) return _parent.X - 1;
            return _x;
        }
    }
    public int Y
    {
        get
        {
            if (_parent != null) return _parent.Y;
            return _y;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make brick1 a derived class with a calculated read only property

```
 public class childBrick: Brick
 {
     public new float X 
     {
         get { return base.X - 1.0 } 
         private set { base.X = value; }
     }
     public static Brick Make( float x, float y)
     {
         return new childBrick
         { 
            X = x;
            Y = y;
         }
     }
 }
```

use it like this

```
 Brick brick1 = childBrick.Make(parent.X - 1,parent.Y);
```

Comment: not sure inheritance is what OP need. in his code `parent` seems not be be a parent class, but an object of same class with a parent relationship with brick1

Comment: but since childBrick *is a* Brick, it will work just fine to accomplish what he wants